# I have too many partitions, and would like to have less, but some have a lot of data on them

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, partitioning

[image]

I have a lot of data on my F: that I want to keep, and I would like to not have to reinstall windows on S:, since I have many softwares and drivers and updates.

If I move all the data which is on F to the 244GB partition (which is just before S), will I be able to "extend" my S partition so it can take the remaining space ?

I already did that before, it changed those partitions to dynamic, it was a hell to change back, I was afraid to have lost data etc, but managed to back it up before reinstalling windows, so I use partition wizard, but reinstalling windows on the 244GB partition restored my previous S installation.

So I'm a little cautious and that's why I'm asking here, should I just use the other windows installation and forget about S, or will I be able to resize my S partition if I remove F ? (after backing up my files of course.)

Comment: You don't have enough space on the 244 GB patition for all of the files on F: ...

Comment: Yes, if you move your files and get rid of the extended partition (F), you should have no problems resizing S to take up the free space.

Comment: Extra care must be taken to remove the extended partition (green border), otherwise Windows won’t let you extend the S: partition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may not be able to move all files to the 244GB partition due to not enough free space problem. I can't see how many free space is available from the above figure. Just backup to a portable HDD if you have one (or cloud storage whatever.. I think this is not the main problem for you.)

Since F: currently is `Logical Drive`, you have to fully delete F: and the change back the `logical pool` to `primary pool`, then DO NOT create any partition then  you will be able to extend S: if you are running Windows 7 or after.